# Difference between execute groovy script and the execute system groovy script in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

Can anyone explain the different between the execute groovy script and the execute system groovy script in jenkins? And how to call the script to slave using execute system groovy script.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To execute a groovy script on the slave machine, you should use [groovy plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin)

Quote

> The plain "Groovy Script" is run in a forked JVM, on the slave where
>   the build is run. It's the basically the same as running the "groovy"
>   command and pass in the script.

First part of your question is answered in the same page

> The system groovy script, OTOH, runs inside the Hudson master's JVM.
>   Thus it will have access to all the internal objects of Hudson, so you
>   can use this to alter the state of Hudson. It is similar to the
>   Jenkins Script Console functionality.

Comment: So what is "system groovy script"? Is my project pipeline script a system one?

Answer (score 1):

Another point on system Groovy scripts to be aware of.  While the documentation says that it always runs on the Jenkins master, I've found through painful means that it isn't true if it's in a job that is triggered by another job.  In that case, make sure you specifically restrict it to run on the master or bad things will happen.

Comment: This response isn't quite true. System Groovy scripts are used to access the Jenkins internals (e.g. Job/Build/Queue information) and as such the script itself run's on the Jenkins master, inside the Jenkins master JVM, regardless of which slave the job itself is running on.  As an example, our Jenkins master has no executors, and never runs the builds. They are always run on the slaves, however the System Groovy scripts still run on the master JVM.