# How to access maven property from Jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-3, pom.xml

I have a maven project in which I have a property. I want to access it from Jenkins.

POM snippet:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <timestamp>${build.time}</timestamp>
    <outputFolder>C:/AutomationTestReports/${project.name}/ExecutionReport${timestamp}</outputFolder>
</properties>
```

This output folder property gets evaluated at runtime. I want to access this property in Jenkins to navigate to the output folder which gets generated as per the time stamp. For this to happen I need to capture this output folder property in Jenkins, which I am not able to do.

Using this output folder only I will be able to navigate to the folder to access the result file.

**Question**: How to access Maven properties from Jenkins job?

Comment: According to this article - https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/07/accessing-maven-project-properties-jenkins-build-jobs/, It seems we can access some aspects of the pom.xml in a Jenkins job. Can you try if this works? Maybe make this <outputFolder> as a unique tag in the pom, and try to access it as shown? Just a trial, Not sure if this will work. I don't have a Jenkins to try.

Comment: I know the link mentions some standard pom variables, but worth trying IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jenkins Maven jobs provide by default some [maven properties](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+maven2+project) to be used during job configuration, however it doesn't provide any easy access to further properties defined into the pom file.

Hence, a custom approach is required. Here is a working solution which makes use of a groovy script and could be used to transform any defined Maven property into a new Jenkins variable at build time, to be then further used in additional post build steps.

Pre-requirements to this solution are:

- Groovy is installed in the Jenkins server (easy step, just [download it](http://groovy-lang.org/download.html), unzip, set it to the path
- The [Jenkins Groovy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin) is installed in Jenkins (easy step, *Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins, Available Plugins*, install it, then configure it under *Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Groovy*, to make it point to the installation of step above

You can then add to the project pom the following to is `build/plugins` section:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>write-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/build.properties</outputFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**What are we doing?** Simply using the [`properties-maven-plugin`](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin) and its [`write-project-properties`](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/write-project-properties-mojo.html) goal to write the project properties into a new file under the target folder (`target\build.properties`). Note: properties in this file will **already be interpolated**.
This new file will be harmless for your build and project, ignored by any other build step, removed as part of a `mvn clean` invocation, but yet **really helpful** for Jenkins.

Then, in the concerned Jenkins job you can add a new *Post Steps > Execute system Groovy script* (and not an *Execute Groovy script*, bear the [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634733/difference-between-execute-groovy-script-and-the-execute-system-grovy-script-in)) pointing to a new groovy file you can store where desired or type into the console the following groovy code:

```
import hudson.model.*;
import hudson.util.*;

def thr = Thread.currentThread();
def currentBuild = thr?.executable;

def props = new Properties();
new File(currentBuild.workspace.toString()+"\\target\\build.properties").withInputStream { 
  stream -> props.load(stream);
}

println "detected from properties: "+props.get("outputFolder");

def newParamAction = new ParametersAction(new StringParameterValue("outputFolder", props.get("outputFolder")));
currentBuild.addAction(newParamAction);
```

**What is this script doing?** Simply reading the property file, printing to the console the `outputFolder` property as a log (to be removed, optionally) and then set it as a new Jenkins job variable with the same name (to be changed if required).

You can then use in further post build steps the `${outputFolder}` new variable (or the `%outputFolder%` in Windows commands) and it will be correctly present.

As an example, you can debug it via a new Post Steps > Execute Windows Batch command and simply echo it. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

As output of a sample Jenkins job you would then have:

```
detected from properties: C:/AutomationTestReports/sample-project/Execution_(2016-04-24_12-11-13UTC)
[workspace] $ cmd /c call C:\dev\tomcat-7\temp\hudson6024790907972070905.bat

C:\Users\user-name\.jenkins\jobs\sample-maven\workspace>echo C:/AutomationTestReports/sample-project/Execution_(2016-04-24_12-11-13UTC) 
C:/AutomationTestReports/sample-project/Execution_(2016-04-24_12-11-13UTC)

C:\Users\user-name\.jenkins\jobs\sample-maven\workspace>exit 0 
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: It's much less intrusive on the POM to let Jenkins read it and access the relevant properties from there. `def pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'; echo pom.properties['timestamp']`

Answer (score 4):

In the current version of Jenkins there is a nice and simple way to achieve this using "readMavenPom()".

For example, I want to read the version of the pom.xml file. But if it is using the newer maven "revision" practice, I need to read that "revision" value from the properties defined in the pom.xml.

```
      def pomVersion = readMavenPom().version   // read version
      if (pomVersion.equals("\${revision}"))    // using revision strategy, read revision property
      {
        pomVersion = readMavenPom().properties['revision']
      }
```

So the best way is to use

```
readMavenPom().properties['PROPETY_NAME']
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty solution.

Add an 'Execute Shell' step, and assign the property's value into a variable:

```
outputFolderVar=$(awk -F '[<>]' '/outputFolder/{print $3}' pom.xml)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
environment {
       OUTPUT_FOLDER = "${sh(script: 'mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=outputFolder -q -DforceStdout', returnStdout: true)}"
    }
```

[pipeline-utility-steps](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).